# How do I resolve Invalid Hook call error in React when trying to use route/navigate

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm working on a project currently and keep getting this error with my routing:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at Object.throwInvalidHookError (react-dom.development.js:16227:1)
    at Object.useContext (react.development.js:1618:1)
    at useInRouterContext (hooks.tsx:85:1)
    at Navigate (components.tsx:196:1)
    at Login.jsx:24:1
```

This is the components of the app that I've got coded:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");

  const submitForm = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/users")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const user = data.find(
          (user) =>
            user.email &&
            user.email.toLowerCase() === email.toLowerCase() &&
            user.password &&
            user.password.toLowerCase() === password.toLowerCase()
        );
        if (user) {
          Navigate("/profile");
        } else {
          setErrorMessage("Invalid email or password");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email">Enter Email Address:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="email"
            id="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="password">Enter Password:</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            id="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
      {errorMessage && <p>{errorMessage}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Profile from "./components/Profile";
import Login from "./components/Login";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>Application</h1>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";


const Profile = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Dashboard</h2>
      <p>Welcome to your profile page!</p>
      {/* Display user profile information here */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

I've tried several fixes, such as reinstalling VSCode/Node.js, starting a new React app, using npm link ../myapp/node_modules/react... Most fixes I could find in the last 24 hours.

This is my current react versions:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin\Documents\SD Semester2\Final_Sprint\finalsprint> npm ls react
finalsprint@0.1.0 C:\Users\Admin\Documents\SD Semester2\Final_Sprint\finalsprint
├─┬ @testing-library/react@13.4.0
├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-router-dom@6.10.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-router@6.10.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
└── react@18.2.0
```

Also, when I try and see the react version on my browser console with React.version, it says that React is not defined.

Comment: [Navigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate) is a React component, not a regular function, so you can't call it as you do in `submitForm` in your `Login` component. It looks like you might be wanting [redirect](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect) instead.

Comment: That was certainly the issue. Thank you. :) Simple, but headache inducing mistake. I added a const for useNavigate() and now I'm back to getting things done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use Navigate directly in your code ,
use this instead

```
const navigate = useNavigate()
```

Here is your code for login file

```
import React, { useState } from "react"; 
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
 import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
    
    const Login = () => {  
 const location = useLocation();   
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
   const [password, setPassword] = useState(""); 
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
const navigate= useNavigate();
    
      const submitForm = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch("http://localhost:8000/users")
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            const user = data.find(
              (user) =>
                user.email &&
                user.email.toLowerCase() === email.toLowerCase() &&
                user.password &&
                user.password.toLowerCase() === password.toLowerCase()
            );
            if (user) {
              navigate("/profile");
            } else {
              setErrorMessage("Invalid email or password");
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => console.log(error));   };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="email">Enter Email Address:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="email"
                id="email"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="password">Enter Password:</label>
              <input
                type="password"
                name="password"
                id="password"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
          </form>
          {errorMessage && <p>{errorMessage}</p>}
        </div>   ); };
    
    export default Login;
```

Comment: This was absolutely the issue. Very simple mistake, but caused quite the headache. Thank you!